# Runing a python file from cmd as administrator (without changing code)

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to run x.py file in cmd but as admin.

There is any command that you add to:

```
python x.py
```

that need to be added to make it work? (I wish to do it without changing the code in the file)

Comment: You need to open an administrator console. This has absolutely nothing to do with python

Comment: Need more info, like OS, which terminal/console you are using, etc. Please edit the question to add more information. If this is Windows (as the term admin implies), just run Command Prompt or Powershell as an administrator when you open it up.

Comment: IS the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in which you can specify a cmd in windows that will perform in an admin mode, e.g. `<cmd> python x.py` is not possible.

The simplest way to do this as @MadPhysicist mentioned is to open the `cmd` line in administrative mode.

There also exists another way in which you can elevate the user rights straight from `cmd` line; this is more or less equivalent to the `sudo` command on Linux but will spawn a new window.

The [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command.

```
runas [{/profile|/noprofile}] [/env] [/netonly] [/smartcard] [/showtrustlevels] [/trustlevel] /user:UserAccountName program
```

Just run:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

to start a command shell as an administrator. You can then run your file the way you want.